# airbnb/lottie animation not working on android 4.4, 4.3 and 4.2

Tags: android, lottie

I am using lottie for animation from [here](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) it is working perfect but it is not working for android 4.4, 4.3 and 4.2 how can fix it. also if I check an animation with lottie preview app in my device which is android API 24 . it says this warning:

> Animation contains merge paths. merge paths are only supported on
>   kitkat+ and must be manually enabled by calling
>   enableMergePathsForKitkatandAbove()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lottie animation not showing at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953963/lottie-animation-not-showing-at-all)

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this in you XML file in the `com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView`

```
app:lottie_enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove="true"
```

Or in your activity

```
vpnStatusAnimView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.anim_view_vpn_status);
vpnStatusAnimView.enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove(true)
```

You will still have that warning message tho..

Comment: XML is not enough?

Comment: this will not change anything below 4.4

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu yes you are right, the problem still accour. what is your prefer?

Comment: Actually I don't understand what shoul i do @Ege

Comment: you don't have to do anything as I stated in my answer. "merge path 4.4 ve altında çalışmıyor mehmet bey malesef animasyonu bu versiyonlarda kullanamazsınız"

Answer (score 2):

For compose:

LottieAnimation(
...,
enableMergePaths = true
)

Answer (score 0):

enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove in XML & Code.

> XML

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
android:id="@+id/anim_view_vpn_status"
android:layout_width="@dimen/lottie_view_width"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_view_top_margin"
app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
app:lottie_enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove="true"
app:lottie_loop="true" />
```

> Code

```
vpnStatusAnimView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.anim_view_vpn_status);
vpnStatusAnimView.enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove(true);
```