# Lottie animation not showing at all

Tags: android, lottie

My import:

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.2.2"
```

In my splash_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"/>

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:lottie_fileName="logo_android.json"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="demo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

In SplashActivity:

```
private LottieAnimationView animationView;
(...)
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
    animationView=findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
    animationView.playAnimation();
(...)
}
```

My image folder is in src/main/res/assets/demo. The logo_android.json file is in src/main/assets

This way, the animation does not show at all. Not a single image is displayed. How can I get the animation working?

In case it matters, the JSON file looks something like this:

```
{"v":"5.5.8","fr":25,"ip":0,"op":400,"w":800,"h":400,"nm":"logo_android","ddd":0,"assets":[{"id":"image_0","w":396,"h":51,"u":"images/","p":"img_0.png","e":0},{"id":"image_1","w":122,"h":215,"u":"images/","p":"img_1.png","e":0},(...)
```

Comment: Yo do not need to call it from code if you have already specified it in xml.

Comment: I didn't have it in code, but due that it was not working I added it in code to try, but didn't work either...

Comment: can't be an issue in your json file? Please try with some from LottieFiles.com

Comment: is animation playing on lottie animation site? if yes try wrap content for height and width

Comment: already tried with wrap content

Comment: I checked the JSON, and has it inside, for every image: "u":"images/" Does it means I have to place the files in a folder called "images"?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

In case it can help someone, you have to put the images in src/main/assets/images

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Expo SDK V44 (React Native V0.64.3), lottie-react-native V5.0.1 and lottie-ios V3.2.3. What I have found that works is to call the `.play()` method on the ref from the `LottieView`, on mount of the component. I referenced this from the official Expo Lottie documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/lottie/.

```js
const animationRef = useRef<LottieView | null>(); // The <> is for TypeScript, but can be removed for JavaScript

  useEffect(() => {
    animationRef.current?.play();
  }, []);

  return (
    <LottieView
      ref={(animation) => {
        animationRef.current = animation;
      }}
      source={require("../path_to_animation_folder)}
      autoPlay
      loop
      style={{ width, height }}
    />
  );
```

Hope I managed to help someone!

Comment: Thanks you managed to help me and unlike expo your example used a functional component.

Comment: Glad I managed to help!

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it working by this:

```
if(lottieTest.getFrame() == lottieTest.getMaxFrame()) {
   lottieTest.setFrame(1);
}
```

please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530232/2828651).